# Switching between workspaces does not refresh the view

Tags: 20.04, gnome, workspaces

When I switch from one workspace to another, the second workspace will have a view of one of the applications of the previous workspace painted on it, I can not interact with this view!

If you wish, take a look at [this screen-recording](https://youtu.be/Gz2n9HbBRcQ) of the issue.

I **can** solve this by restarting GNOME (alt+f2:r), but I want a real solution, I have been using this setup for more than a month, and only now did this start to happen, I installed Steam yesterday, could there be a correlation?

Edit: I discovered another symptom of this glitch which is the fact that `windows + d` does not show desktop, instead it shows a frozen image of whatever app I was on when I pressed the keys. (thanks to
med benzekri for helping me discover this)

Here is the results of running `neofetch`:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               hasan@hasan-Nitro-AN515-43 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Nitro AN515-43 V1.10 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.11.0-43-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 day, 1 hour, 57 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2284 (dpkg), 9 (flatpak), 16 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: fish 3.3.1 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Graphite-dark-nord 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Graphite-nord [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: We10X-special-dark [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mobile 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Picasso 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 4311MiB / 13925MiB
```

Answer (score 1):

try restart gdm

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```

Comment: I tried it but it made no difference, I still get the glitch.

Comment: does `windows+ D` show desktop on that workplace ?

Comment: I just checked and `windows + d` is broken! it does not show desktop; instead, it moves the current window slightly up and renders a frozen image of it.

Comment: have you tried switching to wayland or to x11 if you're already in it

Comment: I guess logging out works, the glitch is gone for now.